# How to ensure if my kernel is configured for using threaded IRQ?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, interrupt-handling

I am trying use threaded interrupt in my platform driver code in my 4.11 Linux kernel. I am at the moment facing random Kernel Crashes. While debugging the problem how can I ensure that my kernel is actually ready for dealing with threaded IRQ. For installing the interrupt handler I am using devm_request_threaded_irq(). Is there a list of patches to check if been applied and/or list of CONFIG_ options to check in my kernel config?

```
ret = devm_request_threaded_irq(dev,
                data->irq,  /* irq number */
                &abc_handle_irq,  /* top half handler */
                &abc_thread_irq,  /* threaded bottom half */
                IRQF_SHARED,
                DEVICE_NAME,
                (void *)pdev);
if (ret) {
    dev_err(dev, "devm_request_threaded_irq() failed: %d\n", ret);
    goto error;
}

/* Top Half */
irqreturn_t abc_handle_irq(struct device *dev)
{
    struct xxx_dev *xxx = dev_get_drvdata(dev);
    int ret = IRQ_HANDLED;
    u32 int_status;

    if (!xxx)
        return IRQ_NONE;
    ...
    ...    
    int_status = ioread32(xxx->reg_base + xxx_INTERRUPT_STATUS);

    if(/* int_status indicates error */) {
        /* ERROR case */
        dev_info(dev, "%s: Got ERROR!\n", __func__);
        /* clear the interrupt */
    }

    if (/* int_status has PICTURE_DONE_IRQ bit set */) {
        /* clear the interrupt */
        ....
        ret = IRQ_WAKE_THREAD;
    } else
        return IRQ_NONE;  /* spurious interrupt not interested */

    return ret;
}

/* Bottom Half */
irqreturn_t xxx_thread_irq(struct device *dev)
{
    struct xxx_dev *xxx = dev_get_drvdata(dev);
    irqreturn_t ret = IRQ_HANDLED;

    if (!xxx)
        return IRQ_NONE;

    dev_info(dev, "%s: IRQ\n", __func__);

    mutex_lock(&xxx->lock); /* lock is shared between the bottom half and a process context */

    /* Spurious interrupt */
    if (unlikely(!xxx->cmd)) {
        dev_err(dev, "%s: No pending encode\n", __func__);

        ret = IRQ_NONE;
        goto out_unlock;
    }

    xxx_yyy_command_completed(abc, pqr, 0);

    kfree(xxx->cmd);
    xxx->cmd = NULL;

out_unlock:
    mutex_unlock(&xxx->lock);
    dev_info(dev, "%s: exiting\n", __func__);
    return ret;
}
```

/* Kernel Crash */

```
[   63.327733] ---[ end trace f1f2a7c1833acf6b ]---
[   63.327787] CPU: 1 PID: 156 Comm: irq/18-abc-xxx Tainted: G        W  O    4.11.0 #6
[   63.327844] task: a80000804f31e680 task.stack: a800008045f7c000
[   63.327886] $ 0   : 0000000000000000 ffffffff80192a30 ffffffffc001f794 0000000000040b00
[   63.327974] $ 4   : 0000000000000012 a80000804f282400 000000001400fde0 ffffffffffff00fe
[   63.328062] $ 8   : fffffffffffffffc a8000000814d0000 0000000000000000 00000000000007ff
[   63.328150] $12   : a800008045f7fdd8 000000000000fd00 0000000000000000 0000000000000000
[   63.328237] $16   : a80000804f991380 ffffffff80192608 a80000804f268a00 a80000804f9913c0
[   63.328326] $20   : ffffffff80190000 ffffffff808c3440 ffffffff808d0000 0000000000000001
[   63.328415] $24   : 0000000000000000 ffffffff80254440                                  
[   63.328501] $28   : a800008045f7c000 a800008045f7fdc0 ffffffff808c3440 ffffffff80192640
[   63.328592] Hi    : a80000804f9913c0
[   63.328625] Lo    : ffffffff80190000
[   63.328691] epc   : ffffffffc001f794 xxx_thread_irq+0x0/0x24 [jsp]
[   63.328747] ra    : ffffffff80192640 irq_thread_fn+0x38/0x64
[   63.328789] Status: 1400fde3 KX SX UX KERNEL EXL IE 
[   63.328868] Cause : 00800400 (ExcCode 00)
[   63.328904] PrId  : 0001a900 (MIPS I6400)
[   63.328950] CPU: 1 PID: 156 Comm: irq/18-aaa-xxx Tainted: G        W  O    4.11.0 #6
[   63.328999] Stack : 0000000000000049 0000000000000049 ffffffff814841da 0000000000000000
[   63.329085]         ffffffff808d0000 0000000000000049 0000000000000049 ffffffff8018de40
[   63.329172]         0000000000000000 ffffffff8018e61c ffffffff808c0000 0000000000000000
[   63.329258]         ffffffff808c0000 ffffffff807aa838 a80000804f31e680 ffffffff8147e5b0
[   63.329346]         000000000000009c 0000000000000001 a80000804f09be7c ffffffff808d0000
[   63.329432]         ffffffff808cc080 ffffffff8018c54c a80000804f09bd20 0000000000040b00
[   63.329520]         ffffffff808c9b87 ffffffff8018f598 0000000000010000 ffffffff807aa838
[   63.329607]         0000000000000001 000000000000009c a80000804f09bc48 0000000000000000
[   63.329693]         ffffffff804a888c 000000001400fde0 0000000000000000 0000000000000000
[   63.329779]         0000000000000000 0000000000000000 ffffffff8010e96c 0000000000040b00
[   63.329865]         ...
[   63.329903] Call Trace:
[   63.329941] [<ffffffff8010e96c>] show_stack+0x68/0xbc
[   63.329994] [<ffffffff804a888c>] dump_stack+0xdc/0x110
[   63.330055] [<ffffffff801be074>] flush_smp_call_function_queue+0x12c/0x1fc
[   63.330119] [<ffffffff80113a44>] ipi_call_interrupt+0x18/0x28
[   63.330177] [<ffffffff80190f9c>] __handle_irq_event_percpu+0xa8/0x25c
[   63.330238] [<ffffffff8019118c>] handle_irq_event_percpu+0x3c/0x98
[   63.330297] [<ffffffff80191240>] handle_irq_event+0x58/0x90
[   63.330355] [<ffffffff80195fc0>] handle_edge_irq+0x168/0x1a4
[   63.330411] [<ffffffff8018feb4>] generic_handle_irq+0x2c/0x3c
[   63.330472] [<ffffffff804e8c74>] gic_irq_dispatch+0x220/0x274
[   63.330528] [<ffffffff8018feb4>] generic_handle_irq+0x2c/0x3c
[   63.330586] [<ffffffff80736a94>] do_IRQ+0x24/0x30
[   63.330642] [<ffffffff804e4f3c>] plat_irq_dispatch+0xf4/0x128
[   63.330697] [<ffffffff80101234>] handle_int+0x134/0x140
[   63.330771] [<ffffffffc001f794>] xxx_thread_irq+0x0/0x24 [jsp]
[   63.330850] [<ffffffff80192640>] irq_thread_fn+0x38/0x64
[   63.330906] [<ffffffff80192a30>] irq_thread+0x144/0x27c
[   63.330961] [<ffffffff8015d368>] kthread+0x180/0x188
[   63.331014] [<ffffffff80100ed4>] ret_from_kernel_thread+0x14/0x1c
```

Comment: For example do I need CONFIG_PREEMPT=y and PREEMPT_RT=y for using threaded IRQ. Any lead would be helpful.

Comment: I have the below set in my kernel config:

CONFIG_PREEMPT_VOLUNTARY=y

But not 
# CONFIG_PREEMPT_NONE is not set
# CONFIG_PREEMPT is not set

Or 

PREEMPT_RT

Comment: CONFIG_PREEMPT is for enabling/disabling the preemption. Okay first thing first, where is the log? Did you check the return value of devm_request_threaded_irq()? Do you see any error code there? if yes, did you validate the code. If possible, why don't you display your module code?

Comment: @LinuxStuff thanks for the reply. No I do not get any error in devm_request_threaded_irq().  But upon receipt of interrupt the interrupt handler IRQ_WAKE_THREAD to kernel. Then the kernel should call the thread function. But the thread function intermittently doesn't get called.

Comment: @LinuxStuff Maybe the threaded handler function is not getting a change to be scheduled. So the question is why? This book https://www.packtpub.com/mapt/book/networking_and_servers/9781784392536/14/ch14lvl1sec151/threaded-interrupt-handlers seems to be suggesting threaded interrupt is a part of the patch PREEMPT_RT patch. Is that correct or I am mistaken here? I understand the standard interrupt handling, but never used/debugged a threaded interrupt handler before.

Comment: @LinuxStuff In the comment section the Ctrl+K doesn't seem to indent my code block. So posting the piece of code which installs the threaded IRQ in the answer section.

Comment: I have updated the question description. You should remove your code from answer section. I don't think this is appropriate.

Comment: @LinuxStuff I have removed the code from answer section but not sure why it is not appropriate? Sorry for being naive here.

Comment: I mean putting question stuff in answer section is not a ideal way.

Comment: what kind of crash messages are you getting when do you say _I am at the moment facing random Kernel Crashes_ ?

Comment: Are you clearing the interrupt properly in top half? Your code snippet doesn't contain that piece exactly.

Comment: @LinuxStuff The main problem I am facing intermittently is that the threaded bottom half is not at all called by the kernel. The kernel crashes are infrequent and maybe red-herring. I want to first fix the issue why the bottom half is not called by Kernel. BTW if I want to post the kernel crash back trace how do I format it in the comment section?

Comment: Yes the top half is clearing the interrupt properly, I have double checked.

Comment: You can add kernel crash by appending the same into your question.

Comment: I have modified the question to include the kernel crash. In the stack trace you will see xxx_thread_irq() in the call chain.

Comment: What the heck is this: _mutex_lock(&xxx->lock); /* lock is shared between the bottom half and a process context */_?! What the heck is that: *kfree(xxx->cmd);*?!

Comment: @0andriy I think that's allowed in a threaded bottom half mechanism.

Comment: Threaded bottom half apparently doesn't run in an atomic context and hence can do things any kernel thread can do. Someone please educate me if this is not correct.

Comment: Yes, but those operations might be quite expensive. And there is no clarification what that comment means.

Comment: Ok maybe "shared" is a wrong choice of word, to put it correctly the mutex protects the critical section from a process and the bottom half.

Comment: I think once we agree a bottom half to behave like any other thread we have to bear the costly operations as well. I am trying to still understand the concept of threaded interrupt/bottom half, if there is any gap in my understanding I am happy to be corrected. Please point out.